# Is there anyway to access webpage content which has an 302 redirect?

Tags: python, http, redirect

Suppose we have a web page on **localhost/helloworld.php** which is a normal PHP page with all normal HTML in it, but the page has been set to redirect to another page with a **response code of 302**

So my question is, is there any way using Python to access those HTML content on localhost/helloworld.php with following protocols and getting redirect to another page?

**Note:** Page is outputting everything normally, but a header is set using PHP's header(); function to redirect to another page temporarily.

Comment: I am sure there is because I did this in c#. I don't know how in php, but have you tried curling the page. I don't think **curl** will follow the redirect. Also if you are interested I can post C# code.

Comment: Probably not. Typically when using the header function to send a 302, the next line is `exit;` (or probably should be), which will obviously stop execution and prevent the page from being able to render.

Comment: It's absolutely possible in terms of HTTP handling, but I'm not too familiar with how python handles this.

Comment: @Radmation Thanks no problems for language I am comfortable with c# too

Comment: @rjdown Assuming there is no exit

Comment: @ext0 So how in HTTP handling?

Comment: Read up on how Python evaluates HTTP status codes. There must be some way to bypass the 302 and get the results from the original request. Maybe see if you can ignore the `Location` HTTP header?